# Map de objeto não retorna todos os dados

Tags: api, typescript, estrutura-de-dados

Estou tentando passar um map em uma api que deve imprimir vídeos em um site. Quando termina de fazer o map ele não está pegando os vídeos da próxima categoria e populando o objeto.
Criei o seguinte JSON para testes:

```js
[
    {
        "id": 1,
        "slug": "futebol",
        "name": "Futebol",
        "videos": [
            {
                "id": 1,
                "link": "https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=CWWOW7T82Hw",
                "title": "Dribles mais humilhates da historia",
                "index": false,
                "image": "no-img.jpg",
                "categories": [
                    {
                        "slug": "futebol",
                        "name": "Futebol"
                    }
                ]
            },
            {
                "id": 2,
                "link": "https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=vOqfupUXkkY",
                "title": "Os movimentos mais bonitos do futebol",
                "index": false,
                "image": "no-img.jpg",
                "categories": [
                    {
                        "slug": "futebol",
                        "name": "Futebol"
                    }
                ]
            }
        ]
    },
    {
        "id": 29,
        "slug": "cachorro",
        "name": "Cachorro",
        "videos": [
            {
                "id": 3,
                "link": "https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=S-gWb3sV9mY",
                "title": "Videos engraçados de cachorro",
                "index": false,
                "image": "no-img.jpg",
                "categories": [
                    {
                        "slug": "cachorro",
                        "name": "Cachorro"
                    }
                ]
            },
            {
                "id": 4,
                "link": "https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Nu5K2IRrsiY",
                "title": "Videos engraçados de cachorro 2",
                "index": false,
                "image": "no-img.jpg",
                "categories": [
                    {
                        "slug": "cachorro",
                        "name": "Cachorro"
                    }
                ]
            }
        ]
    }
]
```

E estou fazendo o seguinte map no objeto:

```js
const [videosObject] = videoCategories.map((item) =>
      item.videos.map((obj) => obj),
)
```

Eu entendi que desestruturando o objeto usando [videosObject, videosObject2] eu consigo pegar todos os dados dos dois objetos do array porém eu queria colocar os 4 objetos de vídeo que estão nos 2 arrays vídeos em somente um objeto do tipo array com esse 4 objetos e imprimir esses dados e não estou sabendo qual o recurso eu utilizo.

Comment: A sua pergunta não ficou clara, qual o resultado desejado no final?

Comment: O resultado final que espero são somente os 4 objetos vídeo que estão dentro dos arrays de vídeos

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Uma maneira de vc conseguir o resultado que deseja e que eu acho a melhor maneira, por ser mais simples, é criar a variável **`videosObject`** como sendo um `array` e simplesmente fazer um **push** nela com os objetos dos vídeos:

```js
let videoCategories = [{
    "id": 1,
    "slug": "futebol",
    "name": "Futebol",
    "videos": [{
        "id": 1,
        "link": "https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=CWWOW7T82Hw",
        "title": "Dribles mais humilhates da historia",
        "index": false,
        "image": "no-img.jpg",
        "categories": [{
          "slug": "futebol",
          "name": "Futebol"
        }]
      },
      {
        "id": 2,
        "link": "https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=vOqfupUXkkY",
        "title": "Os movimentos mais bonitos do futebol",
        "index": false,
        "image": "no-img.jpg",
        "categories": [{
          "slug": "futebol",
          "name": "Futebol"
        }]
      }
    ]
  },
  {
    "id": 29,
    "slug": "cachorro",
    "name": "Cachorro",
    "videos": [{
        "id": 3,
        "link": "https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=S-gWb3sV9mY",
        "title": "Videos engraçados de cachorro",
        "index": false,
        "image": "no-img.jpg",
        "categories": [{
          "slug": "cachorro",
          "name": "Cachorro"
        }]
      },
      {
        "id": 4,
        "link": "https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Nu5K2IRrsiY",
        "title": "Videos engraçados de cachorro 2",
        "index": false,
        "image": "no-img.jpg",
        "categories": [{
          "slug": "cachorro",
          "name": "Cachorro"
        }]
      }
    ]
  }
]

let videosObject = [];

videoCategories.map(item => item.videos.map(obj => videosObject.push(obj)))

console.log(videosObject)
```

Agora se quiser manter a maneira que fez `desestruturando` os objetos com os vídeos e guardando nas variáveis **`[videosObject, videosObject2]`**, irá precisar de outra variável e nesta nova variável juntar os objetos dos vídeos utilizando [spread operator (...)](https://developer.mozilla.org/pt-BR/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Spread_operator)

```js
let videoCategories = [{
    "id": 1,
    "slug": "futebol",
    "name": "Futebol",
    "videos": [{
        "id": 1,
        "link": "https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=CWWOW7T82Hw",
        "title": "Dribles mais humilhates da historia",
        "index": false,
        "image": "no-img.jpg",
        "categories": [{
          "slug": "futebol",
          "name": "Futebol"
        }]
      },
      {
        "id": 2,
        "link": "https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=vOqfupUXkkY",
        "title": "Os movimentos mais bonitos do futebol",
        "index": false,
        "image": "no-img.jpg",
        "categories": [{
          "slug": "futebol",
          "name": "Futebol"
        }]
      }
    ]
  },
  {
    "id": 29,
    "slug": "cachorro",
    "name": "Cachorro",
    "videos": [{
        "id": 3,
        "link": "https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=S-gWb3sV9mY",
        "title": "Videos engraçados de cachorro",
        "index": false,
        "image": "no-img.jpg",
        "categories": [{
          "slug": "cachorro",
          "name": "Cachorro"
        }]
      },
      {
        "id": 4,
        "link": "https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Nu5K2IRrsiY",
        "title": "Videos engraçados de cachorro 2",
        "index": false,
        "image": "no-img.jpg",
        "categories": [{
          "slug": "cachorro",
          "name": "Cachorro"
        }]
      }
    ]
  }
]

const [videosObject, videosObject2] = videoCategories.map(item => item.videos.map(obj => obj))

const videos = [...videosObject, ...videosObject2]
console.log(videos)
```

Comment: Cara era isso msm que eu estava tentando fazer e não estava conseguindo, tanto a sua resposta quanto a do vigílio resolvem o problema mas eu vou usar a sua pois ela ta usando o map que eu queria. Muito obrigado.

Answer (score 1):

Maneira de resgatar somente os videos é interar em cada posição e copiar da chave os seus videos e transferir para um `array` exemplo:

```js
const global = [
    {
        "id": 1,
        "slug": "futebol",
        "name": "Futebol",
        "videos": [
            {
                "id": 1,
                "link": "https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=CWWOW7T82Hw",
                "title": "Dribles mais humilhates da historia",
                "index": false,
                "image": "no-img.jpg",
                "categories": [
                    {
                        "slug": "futebol",
                        "name": "Futebol"
                    }
                ]
            },
            {
                "id": 2,
                "link": "https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=vOqfupUXkkY",
                "title": "Os movimentos mais bonitos do futebol",
                "index": false,
                "image": "no-img.jpg",
                "categories": [
                    {
                        "slug": "futebol",
                        "name": "Futebol"
                    }
                ]
            }
        ]
    },
    {
        "id": 29,
        "slug": "cachorro",
        "name": "Cachorro",
        "videos": [
            {
                "id": 3,
                "link": "https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=S-gWb3sV9mY",
                "title": "Videos engraçados de cachorro",
                "index": false,
                "image": "no-img.jpg",
                "categories": [
                    {
                        "slug": "cachorro",
                        "name": "Cachorro"
                    }
                ]
            },
            {
                "id": 4,
                "link": "https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Nu5K2IRrsiY",
                "title": "Videos engraçados de cachorro 2",
                "index": false,
                "image": "no-img.jpg",
                "categories": [
                    {
                        "slug": "cachorro",
                        "name": "Cachorro"
                    }
                ]
            }
        ]
    }
];
let videos = [];
for(i = 0; i < global.length; i++) {
  videos = [...videos, ...global[i].videos];
}
console.log(videos);
```

Comment: Muito obrigado pela ajuda, sua resposta também resolve o problema que eu estava tendo dificuldades em resolver. Estava faz dois dias tentando resolver esse problema de lógica.